# Download .txt.gz with ruby

Tags: ruby, gzip

Apple have an API that I would like to download the sales reports data from apple.
The response if all is valid is a .txt.gz file, all my various attempts have failed to properly download the file and not time out
Eg:

```
token = JWT.encode(
   {
    iss: ISSUER_ID,
    exp: Time.now.to_i + 20 * 60,
    aud: "appstoreconnect-v1"
   },
   private_key,
   "ES256",
   header_fields={
     kid: KEY_ID }
 )
puts token

max_retries = 3
times_retried = 0
begin
    filename = "fiance_monthly.txt.gz"
    File.open(filename, "w") do |file|
    file.binmode
    HTTParty.get("https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/salesReports?filter[frequency]=MONTHLY&filter[reportSubType]=SUMMARY&filter[reportType]=SALES&filter[vendorNumber]=&filter[reportDate]=2018-11", 
        :query => {},
        :headers => { 
            "Authorization" => "Bearer " + token,
            "Content-Type" => "application/a-gzip",
            "Transfer-Encoding" => "chunked",
            "Connection" => "keep-alive",
            "Content-Encoding" => "agzip",
        }, 
        stream_body: true) do |fragment|
            file.write(fragment)
        end
        puts "done"
    end
  rescue Net::ReadTimeout => error
    if times_retried < max_retries
      times_retried += 1
      puts "Failed to <do the thing>, retry #{times_retried}/#{max_retries}"
      retry
    else
      puts "Exiting script. <explanation of why this is unlikely to recover>"
      exit(1)
    end
  end
```

This causes Net::ReadTimeout

The response headers are as follows from a postman request:

```
Server →daiquiri/3.0.0
Date →Thu, 13 Dec 2018 06:07:58 GMT
Content-Type →application/a-gzip
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
Connection →keep-alive
requestId →d2abe752-303f-4bad-917c-6e3366219ada
Content-Encoding →agzip
Content-Disposition →attachment;filename=S_M_85484293_201811.txt.gz
x-reports-filename →S_M_85484293_201811.txt.gz
x-reports-download-version →1_0
Strict-Transport-Security →max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-XSS-Protection →1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
Host →reportingitc-reporter-internal.corp.apple.com
X-Frame-Options →SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-ID →UHNUNKBJS5KAEN7BZGZKY52L
X-Rate-Limit →user-hour-lim:3600;user-hour-rem:3596;
x-daiquiri-instance →daiquiri:38493001:pv50p00it-hyhk12043901:7987:18Q34
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I download this file with ruby

Comment: @Cacoon: [spaceship](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/spaceship) is wrapping all of your code. may you'd like to take a look at it...